# Checking if a string is a part of a map

Tags: c++, dictionary, range

I have a map with a string domain and string range.  How would I check if a certain string domain that a user enters is a part of the map? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use find to check if a key is present in a map. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/

Comment: a Google search could ::find that.

Answer (score 1):

use map::find to see if the key is in there